# How to put resource value of property tag in backlog into application.properties

Tags: spring-boot, logback

I have **logback-spring.xml** that contains my configuration and I have another file **log.properties** that I put values that I am using in **logback-spring.xml** in it and added to my **logback-spring.xml** by using `<property resource= />` tag.

what I need is to retrieve the value for this property tag from **application.properties**, right now I directly use the address `<property resource="config/properties/log.properties" />`

following is the structure of files:

-- src/main/resources 
----- config 
-------- logging 
----------- logback-spring.xml 
-------- properties 
----------- log.properties 
-------- application.properties

As I read other questions I tried some of them but they didn't work, I tried the following solutions: 
I added `log.properties=classpath:config/properties/log.properties` to **application.properties** and then added `<property resource="${log.properties}" />` tag to **logback-spring.xml** but it didn't work.

then I tried these two tags together 
`<property resource="application.properties" />` 
`<property resource="${log.properties}" />`

unfortunately still no chance, I am wondering if it is possible at all or not, if I can't retrieve a valuer for `<property/>` tag from **application.properties** then how I can externalize this hard-coded value?

Answer (score 0):

I found that the problem was with addresses so I changed the value in my **logback-spring.xml** and **application.properties** as follow:

**log.properties**
`<property resource="config/application.properties" />` 
**application.properties** 
`log.properties=config/properties/log.properties`

It is now working fine but still, I am not sure it is a good practice to have two `<property>` tags in **logback-spring.xml** or there is a better way to do this?